# Detecting Files using bash

Tags: bash

I am working on test framework where test framework should be intelligent enough to detect what kind of test case it is , based on an existence of  some files in a test folder(each folder has one test case). I have 3 types of test cases .

1. Type A  (detected by presence of $FILENAME_TEST)
2. Type B  (detected by presence of $FILENAME_TEST_B)
3. Combination of Type A and B (detected by presence of both $FILENAME_TEST and $FILENAME_TEST_B)

Below is the test script that check only existence of one type of test case.

```
enter code here

# search all given paths for test directories (containing $FILENAME_TEST)
IFS=$'\n' PATHS_TEST=( $( \
  find "${PATHS_FIND[@]}" -name "$FILENAME_TEST" \
  | sed -e "s:/$FILENAME_TEST$::" \
  | sort | distribute_special_tests '*Workstation_*' ))
log_info "Number of Type A tests in the given paths: ${#PATHS_TEST[@]}"   '`
```

I want to modify above code in such a way that it should detect all three type of test cases.

How can I modify the script for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find support OR ('-o') operator in conditions, so it's relatively easy to allow for multiple pattern. Sed support the '|' for alternate patterns using extended RE '|'.

Updated Script:

```
IFS=$'\n' PATHS_TEST=( $( \
  | find "${PATHS_FIND[@]}" '(' -name "$FILENAME_TEST" -o -name "$FILENAME_TEST_B" -o -name "$FILE_NAME_B" ')'
  | sed -E -e "s:/($FILENAME_TEST$|$FILENAME_TEST_B|$FILE_NAME_B)::" \
  | sort -u \
  | distribute_special_tests '*Workstation_*' ))
log_info "Number of Type A tests in the given paths: ${#PATHS_TEST[@]}"   '`
```

Note: Bash has simplified syntax for pipeline, where if the last character on a line in '|', the continuation characters '\' is not needed.  The above can be written;

```
IFS=$'\n' PATHS_TEST=( $( \
  find "${PATHS_FIND[@]}" '(' -name "$FILENAME_TEST" -o -name "$FILENAME_TEST_B" -o -name "$FILE_NAME_B" ')' |
  sed -E -e "s:/($FILENAME_TEST$|$FILENAME_TEST_B|$FILE_NAME_B)::" |
  sort -u |
  distribute_special_tests '*Workstation_*' ))
log_info "Number of Type A tests in the given paths: ${#PATHS_TEST[@]}"   '`
```

Comment: If $FILENAME_TEST and $FILENAME_TEST_B both are present in a folder then it should detect as a single test case. In the above solution , if both files are present , then it is detecting as 2 tests cases.

Comment: @kernel Question refers to `$FILE_NAME_B` (third case), but from comment looks like you really mean `$FILENAME_TEST_B`. Can you confirm/clarify ?

Comment: -o It was mistake from my side. I have corrected it

Comment: @kernel, there is still a typo: $FILENAME_TEST_B vs $FILENAME_TEST_B.

Comment: @kernel script modified (add -u to get only unique name), which will make them a single test case.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get directories containing file1.txt and file2.txt
first=($(find -name file1.txt -exec dirname {} \;))
second=($(find -name file2.txt -exec dirname {} \;))

# find intersection of $first and $second
for item in "${first[@]}"; do
    if [[ " ${second[@]} " =~ " $item " ]]; then
        both+=($item)
        first=("${first[@]/$item}")
        second=("${second[@]/$item}")
    fi
done

echo "directories containing file1.txt and not file2.txt: ${first[@]}"
echo "directories containing file2.txt and not file1.txt: ${second[@]}"
echo "directories containing both: ${both[@]}"
```

suppose directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── dir2
│   └── file2.txt
├── file1.txt
└── script.sh
```

running the script outputs:

```
directories containing file1.txt and not file2.txt: . 
directories containing file2.txt and not file1.txt: ./dir2 
directories containing both: ./dir1
```